# How to redirect to / execute 1 script from another PHP script in Paypal IPN handler?

Tags: php, joomla, paypal-ipn

I've set up a PHP IPN Paypal notification handler on my site to notify me of payments through PayPal. I have a Joomla install which uses an elaborate, uncommented and undocumented component for processing bookings.

I know I need to call a certain PHP script with a series of arguments once a valid IPN has been received. However, as it's Joomla I have the script in the form:

/index.php?option=com_component&controller=contr

Though obviously this isn't the actual PHP script - like I say, an elaborate framework in MVC.

What is the best method to then call this script? I was thinking of using

```
header("Location: index.php?opt....");
```

however given I've got processing before (with no output) and potentially processing after, I'm not sure if this is the best call.

Appreciate this question is rather obtuse, but any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php), if it's installed/enabled on your server.

```
$ch = curl_init("path/to/your/script.php");

//Include your headers here
$headers = array('');

//Set the data you want to send, as an associative array.
$postData = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if($output == FALSE){
    // Error reporting
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I agree, I have to call an external script as well and curl is the best way to accomplish this. you can't count on paypal to follow a header redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on PayPal to follow your redirect, or at least I wouldn't.

How about including the php-script that you want to invoke?

Comment: I had thought about that, but some initial testing seemed not to work. I'll try it again and see if it works.

Comment: You will have all variables available in the included page as well, meaning all $_POST and $_GET variables from the IPN.